# Enabling ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in xamarin.ios project not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.iOS project, and I've enabled ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) using the following setting in the "Additional mtouch arguments" field on the iOS Build tab: -gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc". However, when I analyze my resulting IPA file using the tool https://mobsf.live/, I'm getting a false result for the ARC flag.

I understand that ARC memory management option designed for Objective-C, and Xamarin.iOS primarily involves working with C# rather than Objective-C. My question is whether it's possible to enable ARC for a Xamarin.iOS project and have it recognized correctly when analyzing the IPA file with tools like mobsf.live.

Has anyone successfully configured ARC for a Xamarin.iOS project, or is there a different approach or tool I should be using to ensure that the ARC flag is correctly identified in the IPA file? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Xamarin ios has [New Reference Counting System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/newrefcount). You may check if you have [Enabled the New Reference Counting System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/newrefcount#enabling-the-new-reference-counting-system).

Comment: Hi @LiqunShen-MSFT 
I have already  tried this, but still no luck

Comment: I saw this [security issues - Enabling ARC](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/19413) you posted. And rolfbjarne has explained the reason. You could track on this thread.